# Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined with Nodejs and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I tryng to get a Token with a postman req and the errors ocurrs...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
>   at User.getByEmail (server/modules/User/service.ts:47:23)
>   at TokenRoutes.auth (server/modules/Auth/auth.ts:18:8)

Heres the code:

**controller.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import * as HTTPStatus from 'http-status';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { onError } from '../../api/responses/errorHandler';
import { onSuccess } from '../../api/responses/successHandler';
import { dbErrorHandler } from '../../config/dbErrorHandler';
import User from './service';

class UserController {

  constructor() {}

  getAll(req: Request, res: Response){
    User
      .getAll()
      .then(_.partial(onSuccess, res))
      .catch(_.partial(onError, res, `Erro ao buscar todos os usuários`))
  }

  createUser(req: Request, res: Response){
    User
      .create(req.body)
      .then(_.partial(onSuccess, res))
      .catch(_.partial(dbErrorHandler, res))
      .catch(_.partial(onError, res, `Erro ao inserir novo usuário`))
  }

  getById(req: Request, res: Response){
    const userId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    User.getById(userId)
      .then(_.partial(onSuccess, res))
      .catch(_.partial(onError, res, `Usuário não encontrado`))
  }

  updateUser(req: Request, res: Response){
    const userId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    const props = req.body;
    User.update(userId, props)
      .then(_.partial(onSuccess, res))
      .catch(_.partial(onError, res, `Erro ao atualizar usuário`))
  }

  deleteUser(req: Request, res: Response){
    const userId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    User.delete(userId)
      .then(_.partial(onSuccess, res))
      .catch(_.partial(onError, res, `Erro ao deletar usuário`))
  }
}

export default new UserController();
```

**routes.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import UserController from './controller';


class UserRoutes {

  constructor(){}

  index(req: Request, res: Response){
    return UserController.getAll(req, res);
  }

  create(req: Request, res: Response){
    return UserController.createUser(req, res);
  }

  findOne(req: Request, res: Response){
    return UserController.getById(req, res);
  }

  update(req: Request, res: Response){
    return UserController.updateUser(req, res);
  }

  destroy(req: Request, res: Response){
    return UserController.deleteUser(req, res);
  }
}

export default new UserRoutes();
```

**service.ts**

```
import { IUser, IUserDetail, createUser, createUsers, createUserById, createUserByEmail } from './interface';
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';
const model = require('../../models');

class User implements IUser {
  public id: number;
  public nm_usuario: string;
  public nm_email_usuario: string;
  public cd_senha_usuario: string;
  public nm_tipo_usuario: string;
  public cd_cnpj_usuario: number;
  public cd_cpf_usuario: number;
  public nm_razao_social_usuario: string;
  public nm_sexo_usuario: string;
  public cd_cep_usuario: number;
  public nm_estado_usuario: string;
  public dt_nascimento_usuario: Date;
  public nm_cidade_usuario: string;
  public cd_telefone_usuario: number;
  public cd_ip_usuario: string;
  public nm_endereco_usuario: string;
  public cd_numero_endereco_usuario: number;
  public ds_complemento_endereco_usuario: string;
  public ds_foto_usuario: string;

  constructor(){}

  create(user: any){
    return model.User.create(user);
  }

  getAll(): Bluebird<IUser[]>{
    return model.User.findAll({
      order: ['nm_usuario']
    })
    .then(createUsers);
  }

  getById(id: number): Bluebird<IUserDetail>{
    return model.User.findOne({
      where: { id }
    })
    .then(createUserById);
  }

  getByEmail(nm_email_usuario: string): Bluebird<IUserDetail>{
    return model.User.findOne({
      where: { nm_email_usuario }
    })
    .then(createUserByEmail);
  }

  update(id: number, user: any){
    return model.User.update(user, {
      where: { id },
      fields: ['nm_usuario', 'nm_email_usuario','cd_senha_usuario','nm_tipo_usuario','cd_cnpj_usuario','cd_cpf_usuario','nm_razao_social_usuario','nm_sexo_usuario','cd_cep_usuario','nm_estado_usuario','dt_nascimento_usuario','nm_cidade_usuario','cd_telefone_usuario','cd_ip_usuario','nm_endereco_usuario','cd_numero_endereco_usuario','ds_complemento_endereco_usuario','ds_foto_usuario'],
      hooks: true,
      individualHooks: true
    });
  }

  delete(id: number){
    return model.User.destroy({
      where: { id }
    });
  }
}

export default new User();
```

**auth.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import User from '../User/service';
import authSuccess from '../../api/responses/authSuccess';
import authFail from '../../api/responses/authFail';


class TokenRoutes {

  auth(req: Request, res: Response){
    const credentials = {
      nm_email_usuario: req.body.nm_email_usuario,
      cd_senha_usuario: req.body.cd_senha_usuario
    };

    if(credentials.hasOwnProperty('nm_email_usuario') && credentials.hasOwnProperty('cd_senha_usuario')){
      User
      .getByEmail(credentials.nm_email_usuario)
      .then(_.partial(authSuccess, res, credentials))
      .catch(_.partial(authFail, req, res));
    }
  }
}

export default new TokenRoutes();
```

So... postman giveme a error 500, probably because can't to execute the method findOne.

Comment: The error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined` seems to be quite clear. You have written `model.User.findOne` in your `getByEmail` method of service.ts. The error says that `model.User` is undefined. It seems your models folder doesn't properly export the user model. try prining (`console.log(model)`) in the service.ts at line 47(the error shows the proper line no.)

Comment: The error was i return Usuario in userModel and call model.User

Comment: Ok that's why model.user was undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a defined as return is `Usuario in userModel`

And I call `model.User`

So I call this... call `model.Usuario` and works